# Custom Homepage As Single Page or Custom Post Type?

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, page-template, homepage, template-hierarchy

Conceptual question for the WP community:

I need to implement a custom homepage for a new site. It has some custom stuff going on but nothing too crazy: 4 big images, a carousel, some calls to action and a list of post at the bottom.

I see two paths, neither of them particularly great:

1. Do a custom HTML layout, add text/image/layouts asset via GUI in Page post-type, then add a custom template for just that node.
2. Create a custom post type w/ ACF for the homepage and put a post-type template.

Path 1 seems hacky and hard to update for a non-dev, path 2 seems easy to update but overkill since the site only requires one homepage. What is best practice? Maybe you have a different approach altogether?

Comment: I don't see why the first is harder than the second. In fact, the second looks more complicated to me. I should note that this strikes me as a "subject to opinion" question and as such would be off topic.

Comment: If there is a best-practice way to do this, it would be beneficial to know. Maybe it is a subjective thing though - kinda why I asked the question ;)

Comment: I always use front-page.php for the home page. And most often Homepages are unique, and need their own code.

Comment: "best" probably depends on your precise requirements.